# Cont monad shift

Tags: haskell, continuations, delimited-continuations

While trying to build some intuition for the ContT monad transformer I (perhaps unsurprisingly) found myself confused. The issue lies with the shiftT operation which doesn't seem to do anything useful.

First a simplistic example of how one might use it

```
shiftT $ \famr -> lift $ do
  a <- calculateAFromEnvironment
  famr a
```

`famr a` could be some more complex expression as long as it returns some `m r`. Now an attempt to explain my intuition that shiftT is doesn't add anything:

```
-- inline shiftT
ContT (\f2 -> evalContT ((\f1 -> lift (do
  a <- calculateAFromEnvironment
  f1 a)) f2))

-- beta reduction
ContT (\f2 -> evalContT (lift (do
  a <- calculateAFromEnvironment
  f2 a)))

-- inline evalConT
ContT (\f2 -> runContT (lift (do
  a <- calculateAFromEnvironment
  f2 a)) return)

-- inline lift
ContT (\f2 -> runContT (ContT (\f3 -> (do
  a <- calculateAFromEnvironment
  f2 a) >>= f3)) return)

-- apply runConT
ContT (\f2 -> (\f3 -> (do
  a <- calculateAFromEnvironment
  f2 a) >>= f3) return)

-- beta reduce
ContT (\f2 -> (do
  a <- calculateAFromEnvironment
  f2 a) >>= return)

-- (>>= return) is identity
ContT $ \f2 -> do
  a <- calculateAFromEnvironment
  f2 a
```

Turns out we could have just build the ContT directly.

Question time: Is there a situation where shift/shiftT add anything over cont/ContT? Or are they just used to make the code more readable?

Comment: All combinators are used to make code more readable. Of course you can build this directly, `shiftT` must be defined in terms of `ContT`. You might find uses of it by [searching github](https://github.com/search?l=Haskell&q=shiftT&type=Code).

Comment: It seems that your beta-reduction step is wrong. In particular `evalContT (\famr -> ...) famr'` doesn't beta-reduce, as `(\famr -> ...)` and `famr'` are arguments to `evalContT`, not a function application.

Comment: @PetrPudlák Thanks, I inlined shiftT as `ContT (\f2-> evalContT f1 f2 )` instead of `ContT (\f2-> evalContT (f1 f2) )`.  Gave up on removing unnecessary brackets so it looks like lisp but I think at least it is correct now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After [searching github](https://github.com/search?l=Haskell&q=shiftT&type=Code) by [Gurkenglas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5318306/gurkenglas)'s advice I've discovered [this very nice explanation](https://github.com/renormalist/pugs/blob/f09558ae9b5ef2cbab75110abc1cb385931329cc/src/Pugs/AST/Eval.hs#L27) of `shiftT` and `resetT` with examples of usages, motivation and semantic!

Those functions are very simple. Their definition in [`transformers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#v:shiftT) library is straightforward:

```
resetT :: (Monad m) => ContT r m r -> ContT r' m r
resetT = lift . evalContT

shiftT :: (Monad m) => ((a -> m r) -> ContT r m r) -> ContT r m a
shiftT f = ContT (evalContT . f)
```

But philosophy and meaning far behind some intuitive understanding. So I recommend you to read explanation from the link above. Sometimes it happens that things that are easy to define actually can do something complex.

Adapted documentation from the explanation in pugs linked above:

> ### `shiftT`
>
> `shiftT` is like `callCC`, except that when you activate the continuation
>   provided by `shiftT`, it will run to the end of the nearest enclosing `resetT`,
>   then jump back to just after the point at which you activated the continuation.
>   Note that because control eventually returns to the point after the 
>   subcontinuation is activated, you can activate it multiple times in the 
>   same block. This is unlike `callCC`'s continuations, which discard the current
>   execution path when activated.
>
> See `resetT` for an example of how these delimited subcontinuations actually
>   work.
>
> ### `resetT`
>
> Create a scope that `shiftT`'s subcontinuations are guaranteed to eventually
>   exit out the end of.  Consider this example:
>
> ```
> resetT $ do
>     alfa
>     bravo
>     x <- shiftT $ \esc -> do   -- note: esc :: m Int, not a ContT
>        charlie
>        lift $ esc 1
>        delta
>        lift $ esc 2
>        return 0
>     zulu x
> ```
>
> This will:
>
> 1. Perform `alfa`
> 2. Perform `bravo`
> 3. Perform `charlie`
> 4. Bind `x` to 1, and thus perform `zulu 1`
> 5. Fall off the end of `resetT`, and jump back to just after `esc 1`
> 6. Perform `delta`
> 7. Bind `x` to 2, and thus perform `zulu 2`
> 8. Fall off the end of `resetT`, and jump back to just after `esc 2`
> 9. Escape from the `resetT`, causing it to yield 0
>
> Thus, unlike `callCC`'s continuations, these subcontinuations will eventually
>   return to the point after they are activated, after falling off the end of the
>   nearest `resetT`.

Comment: But you could just as well say `ContT is like callCC, except that when you activate the function provided by ContT, it will run to the end of the nearest enclosing 'resetT', then jump back to just after the point at which you activated the continuation`. 

In virtually all cases I managed to find shiftT the code would have been (slightly) simpler by using ContT directly.
I did find out that shift and reset are named after implementation details in scheme, though. So maybe its prevalence in other languages with continuations is reason enough too use shift in haskell?

Comment: @Taren It is mostly for code readability. If you're using `ContT` constructor directly it means that you're just creating CPS-like action. It can mean anything. But if you're using `shiftT` and `resetT` functions it gives some hints to code reader about what you're trying to do with them. Understanding code with `Cont` monad is really hard. So having some hints even on the level like _function names_ really can help.

Comment: Thanks for finding this, it's very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

You're right that [delimited continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimited_continuation) can be expressed using undelimited continuations. So the definitions of `shiftT` and `resetT` can be always described using just `ContT`. But:

- Delimited continuations are [less powerful](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/against-callcc.html). This makes them easier to implement and also reason about for humans. (See also a lot of other interesting [posts about continuations](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/) from Oleg Kiselyov).
- Using the familiar notation of *shift/reset* makes it easier to understand, especially for those familiar with the concept.

Essentially, continuations allow to turn a program inside out: The block delimited by `reset` is squeezed inside the inner part of the program, when `shift` calls the passed function. (In the case of undelimited continuations the whole execution context is squeezed inside, which is what makes them so weird.)

Let's make a few examples:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Cont

test0 :: Integer
test0 = evalCont . reset $ do
    return 0
```

If we have `reset` without `shift`, it's just a pure computation, nothing fancy. The above function simply returns `0`.

Now lets use both of them:

```
test1 :: Integer
test1 = evalCont . reset $ do
    r <- shift $ \esc -> do
        let x = esc 2
            y = esc 3
        return $ x * y
    return $ 1 + r
```

This becomes more interesting.
The code between `shift` and `reset` is actually squeezed into the calls of `esc`, in this simple example it's just `return $ 1 + r`. When we invoke `esc`, the whole computation is performed and its result becomes the result of the `esc` call. We do this twice, so essentially we invoke everything between `shift` and `reset` twice. And the result of the whole computation is `result $ x * y`, the result of the `shift` call.

So in a sense, the `shift` block becomes the outer part of the computation and the block between `reset` and `shift` becomes the inner part of the computation.

So far so good. But it becomes even more daunting if we invoke `shift` twice, like in this code sample:

```
list2 :: [(Int, String)]
list2 = evalCont . reset $ do
    x <- shift $ \yieldx ->
        return $ concatMap yieldx [1, 2, 3]
    y <- shift $ \yieldy ->
        return $ concatMap yieldy ["a", "b", "c"]
    return [(x, y)]
```

And here is what it produces (hidden for those who want to try to figure it out as an exercise):

> `[(1,"a"),(1,"b"),(1,"c"),(2,"a"),(2,"b"),(2,"c"),(3,"a"),(3,"b"),(3,"c")]`

Now what happens is that the program is turned inside out *twice*:

1. First everything outside the `x <- shift ...` block is bound to the `yieldx` call, including the next `shift`. And the result of the computation is the result of the `x <- shift ...` block.
2. Second, when invoking the second `y <- shift ...` inside `yieldx`, again the rest of the computation is bound to the `yieldy` call. And the result of this inner computation is the result of the `y <- shift ...` block.

So in `x <- shift` we run the rest of the computation for each of the three arguments, and during each of them, we do a similar thing for each of the other three arguments. The result is then the Cartesian product of the two lists, as we essentially performed two nested loops.

The same thing applies to `shiftT` and `resetT`, just with added side effects. For example, if we want to debug what is actually happening, we can run the above code in the `IO` monad and print debugging statements:

```
list2' :: IO [(Int, String)]
list2' = evalContT . resetT $ do
    x <- shiftT $ \yield ->
        lift . liftM concat . mapM (\n -> print n >> yield n) $ [1, 2, 3]
    y <- shiftT $ \yield ->
        lift . liftM concat . mapM (\n -> print n >> yield n) $ ["a", "b", "c"]
    return [(x, y)]
```