# How is Prolog `shift`/`reset` like other languages?

Tags: haskell, prolog, swi-prolog, continuations, delimited-continuations

I found an example of shift-reset delimited continuations in Haskell [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43697115/257418):

> ```
> resetT $ do
>     alfa
>     bravo
>     x <- shiftT $ \esc -> do
>        charlie
>        lift $ esc 1
>        delta
>        lift $ esc 2
>        return 0
>     zulu x
> ```
>
> This will:
>
> 1. Perform `alfa`
> 2. Perform `bravo`
> 3. Perform `charlie`
> 4. Bind `x` to 1, and thus perform `zulu 1`
> 5. Fall off the end of `resetT`, and jump back to just after `esc 1`
> 6. Perform `delta`
> 7. Bind `x` to 2, and thus perform `zulu 2`
> 8. Fall off the end of `resetT`, and jump back to just after `esc 2`
> 9. Escape from the `resetT`, causing it to yield 0

I can't figure out how to write the equivalent code using SWI-Prolog's [shift/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=shift/1) and [reset/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=reset/3).

The code below is my attempt. The output is the same, but it seems messy and backwards, and I feel like I'm misusing `Ball` to get something similar to the `esc 1` and `esc 2` in the Haskell example. Also, I am not sure what to do with `return 0`.

```
% not sure about this...
example :-
  reset(step, ball(X), Cont),
  ( writeln("charlie"), X=1, call(Cont), fail
  ; writeln("delta"), X=2, call(Cont)).

step :-
  writeln("alfa"),
  writeln("bravo"),
  shift(ball(X)),
  format("zulu ~w~n", X).
```

I'm rather confused: Scheme/Haskell/ML-style shift-reset and Prolog shift-reset seem almost like entirely different things! For example, you pass a lambda into Haskell's `shiftT` but you do not pass a goal into Prolog's shift/1.

Where is the Prolog equivalent of Haskell's `\esc -> ... esc 1` or `return 0`? And where is the Haskell equivalent of Prolog's `Ball` or `call(Cont)`?

I feel that a "proper" port of the Haskell example above would answer these questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The `reset` and `shift` operators originally come from [Danvy; Filinski,1990. “Abstracting Control”](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.6.960&rep=rep1&type=pdf). The corresponding interfaces in Haskell [Control.Monad.Trans.Cont](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html) conform to the original semantics, except for [some type restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72836141/4518482). The delimited continuation interfaces in SWI-Prolog are not exactly the original `reset` and `shift`. They are more closely related to [Felleisen,1988's prompt and control](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/%7Enr/cs257/archive/matthias-felleisen/prompts.pdf) or [Sitaram’s fcontrol and run operators](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.7256).
2. Usually, it is not difficult to translate delimited continuation programs from Haskell to Prolog. The difficulty in your example is that it calls the same continuation `esc` twice with different values. For example,

   ```
   example :-
     reset(step, ball(X), Cont),
     X=1, call(Cont),
     X=2, call(Cont).
   ```

   After the first `call(Cont)`, `X` is already bound to `1`, you cannot rebind it to `2`.

   [TomSchrijvers' advice](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/naming-clarification-about-delimited-continuation-reset-3-and-shift-1/5526/8?u=chansey97) is to create copies of the continuation with fresh unification variables using [copy_term/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=copy_term/2) (yes, continuations are also terms in SWI-Prolog!), so the Prolog equivalent of your example is

   ```
   example(X) :-
     reset(step, Ball, Cont),
     copy_term(Cont+Ball, Cont1+Ball1),
     copy_term(Cont+Ball, Cont2+Ball2),
     writeln("charlie"),
     ball(X1) = Ball1,
     X1=1, reset(Cont1, _, _),
     writeln("delta"),
     ball(X2) = Ball2,
     X2=2, reset(Cont2, _, _),
     X=0.  

   step :-
     writeln("alfa"),
     writeln("bravo"),
     shift(ball(X)),
     format("zulu ~w~n", X),
     shift(ball(X)).

   ?- example(X).
   alfa
   bravo
   charlie
   zulu 1
   delta
   zulu 2
   X = 0.
   ```

More detail discussion, see https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/naming-clarification-about-delimited-continuation-reset-3-and-shift-1