# How to extract delimited continuation (reset/shift) for future use in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, continuations, delimited-continuations

The following is a simple example of using delimited continuation (reset/shift):

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Cont

test :: Integer
test = evalCont . reset $ do
    r <- shift $ \k -> do
        return $ k 10
    return $ 1 + r

λ> test1
11
```

It works well.

However, I'd like to extract the continuation `k` as a pure function for future use, instead of just calling it inside shift.

For example, I hope the `test2`  could return the `k`:

```
test2 :: Integer -> Integer
test2 = evalCont . reset $ do
    r <- shift $ \k -> do
        return $ k
    return $ 1 + r
```

but GHC complains:

```
    ? Couldn't match type 'Integer -> Integer' with 'Integer'
      Expected type: Cont (Integer -> Integer) (Integer -> Integer)
        Actual type: ContT
                       (Integer -> Integer)
                       Data.Functor.Identity.Identity
                       ((Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer)
    ? In a stmt of a 'do' block: return $ k
      In the expression: do return $ k
      In the second argument of '($)', namely '\ k -> do return $ k'
   |
88 |         return $ k
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Anyone could help me to work around this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `r` is supposed to be the `Int -> Int` continuation, right? So you can’t add 1 to it in the last line of `test2`

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson You are right. There is indeed a type mismatch (since Haskell is a static type language). I have added a temporary solution. Correct me if I am wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard `Cont` is incompletely general. "Real" `Cont` looks like this

```
newtype Cont    i o a =    Cont { runCont :: (a -> i) -> o }
-- versus the standard
newtype SadCont   r a = SadCont { sadCont :: (a -> r) -> r }
-- SadCont r a = Cont r r a
```

The standard `SadCont` is used because it supports `>>=` and `return` at their usual types (so it can be a `Monad`). But "real" delimited continuations inside `Cont` allow each `shift` to take values from the continuation at one type and send them up towards the previous `shift`/`reset` at a different type. In this case you are just passing the *entire* continuation as a function from `shift` to `reset`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}
-- ^ placing this at the top of a file or passing -XRebindableSyntax to GHC allows do notation to use custom (>>=) and (>>)

-- not Monad operations!
return :: a -> Cont r r a
return x = Cont ($ x)
(>>=) :: Cont m o a -> (a -> Cont i m b) -> Cont i o b
Cont x >>= f = Cont $ \k -> x (($ k) . runCont . f)
(>>) :: Cont m o a -> Cont i m b -> Cont i o b -- RebindableSyntax also wants this
a >> b = a >>= const b

evalCont :: Cont a o a -> o
evalCont (Cont x) = x id

-- shift/reset are actually just
reset = evalCont
shift = Cont
-- note that the types of reset and shift differ significantly from transformers
-- reset returns a pure value here and shift requires a pure value from its function
-- I think my choices are more correct/standard, e.g. they line up with the old Scala shift/reset http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~hmiller/scaladoc/library/scala/util/continuations/package.html
```

In your example

```
test2 :: Integer -> Integer
test2 = reset $ do
    r <- shift $ \k -> k
    return $ 1 + r
```

TL;DR `Cont` is deliberately "broken", so it loses the generality of differing input and output types but gains `Monad`icity. You can hack around it by putting the input and output types into a (recursive) sum as you've discovered. Alternatively (this answer) you can define and use "real" `Cont`.

Comment: About `shift = Cont`, but why not define `shift f = Cont $ \k -> runCont (f k) id` ? `shift` should support nesting. For example, in Racket `(reset (+ 1 (shift k1 (+ 3 (shift k2 (+ 100 (k2 50))) )) 1000))` returns `153`.

Comment: If `shift = Cont`, you cannot call `shift` inside `shift`. I have improved your `shift` to support nesting: `test3 :: Integer
test3 = reset $ do r <- shift $ \k1 -> do r2 <- shift $ \k2 -> return $ 100 + (k2 50) return $ 3 + r2 return $ 1 + r + 1000`. Now the `test3` could return `153` too.

Comment: For `Cont i o a`, I think you are right. I have upvoted this answer. The `Cont i o a` is indeed better than `Cont r a`. However, if considering Monads' composition (e.g. composing State monad), we might still rollback to the old transformer version with the recursive sum.

Comment: BTW, I just found another delimited continuation library `Control.Monad.CC`, I have not tried it though.

Comment: @chansey My `shift` matches the one in the linked scala continuations library, and you can just `reset` inside `shift` (`shift $ \k -> reset $ _etc`) if you want nesting with it, so I elected *not* to force nesting into it (i.e. my `shift` is the "smallest" `shift`; nesting `shift`s is not fundamental to what `shift` does so it doesn't "belong")

Comment: I see :). My improvement is just to follow the original semantics of reset/shift.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @BenjaminHodgson's comment, here is the temporary solution:

```
data Ret a = Fun (Integer -> Ret a) | Val a

instance Show a => Show (Ret a) where
    show (Fun f) = "Jst f"
    show (Val a) = show a

test2 :: Ret Integer
test2 = evalCont . reset $ do
    r <- shift $ \k -> do
         return $ Fun k
    return $ Val (1 + r)

main :: IO ()
main = do
        print $ case test2 of (Fun f) -> f 100
        print $ case test2 of (Fun f) -> f 50

λ> main
101
51
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sure the recursive type `Ret` is necessary.

I will appreciate if someone could provide a better solution or explanation. Thanks.